# illegal start of simple pattern - play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am newbie to play framework. While trying to generate html template with play, I get the error **illegal start of simple pattern** at the line **ticket.getTicketIds**. Have been spending sometime trying to resolve the issue but of no good.

```
<tbody>
    @for( ticket <- @obj.getPurchasedTickets() ) {
      @for( (key,val) <- @obj.getTicketsCalculation() ) {
       @if( key.equals(ticket.getTicketId())) {
          <tr>
            <td class="desc">@ticket.getTicketName()<br></br>
            @if(ticket.getTicketIds() != null && !ticket.getTicketIds().isEmpty()) {
                @for( ticketid <- ticket.getTicketIds ){
                    #@ticketid 
                }
            }
            </td>
            <td class="unit">@ticket.getPrice()</td>
          </tr>
          }
       }
     }
 </tbody>
```

The following POJOs are used to get the necessary values

```
public class PurchasedTicket {

  private String ticketId; // represents the ticket's id
  private String ticketName;
  private Integer numberOfTickets;
  private Double price;  
  private List<String> ticketIds; // list of tickets bought with this ticket

  // setters and getters
```

}

```
 public class Wrapper{

   private Map ticketsCalculation;
   private List<PurchasedTicket> purchasedTickets;

  // setters and getters
}
```

The obj represented in the template part is an object of **Wrapper** class

Comment: `ticket.getTicketIds` shows a couple of times. Which one?

Comment: The one in  @for( ticketid <- ticket.getTicketIds ){
                    #@ticketid 
                }

Comment: They represent string values.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it right now.
I am curious what's wrong. So `ticket.getTicketIds` is a `List<String>`, right? Did you check with debugger?
Anyway, you are repeating this method, I think you can define new variable, so it will simplify code and maybe you will see what was wrong:
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-values

Comment: There are 2 methods `getTicketIds` (plural) and `getTicketId` (singular), right?

Comment: @Rumid Yes, there are two methods

Comment: Could you create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?
This way I would not need to ask for each part ;)

Comment: @Rumid Updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it compile:

1. As @rouge-one mentioned, you can use different variable name, eg. value.
2. You shouldn't use multiple `@` signs. As [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Syntax:-the-magic-%E2%80%98@%E2%80%99-character) says, it should be used at the beginning of a dynamic statement, eg. `@for( ticket <- obj.getPurchasedTickets() ) {`

   so the working code should look like this:

   ```
   <tbody>
       @for(ticket <- obj.getPurchasedTickets()) {
           @for((key, value) <- obj.getTicketsCalculation()) {
               @if(key.equals(ticket.getTicketId())) {
                   <tr>
                       <td class="desc">@ticket.getTicketName()<br></br>
                           @if(ticket.getTicketIds() != null && !ticket.getTicketIds().isEmpty()) {
                               @for(ticketid <- ticket.getTicketIds){
                                   #@ticketid
                               }
                           }
                       </td>
                       <td class="unit">@ticket.getPrice()</td>
                   </tr>
               }
           }
       }
   </tbody>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

change the attribute name from `val` to `value` in line 3 of your template since `val` is a reserved word.

```
 (key,value) <- @obj.getTicketsCalculation()
```

for example see below

```
scala> val (key, value) =  "key1" -> "val1"
key: String = key1
value: String = val1
```

scala> val (key, value) =  "key1" -> "val1"
key: String = key1
value: String = val1

```
scala> val (key, val) =  "key1" -> "val1"
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple pattern
val (key, val) =  "key1" -> "val1"
          ^
```

Comment: Tried but issue persists

Comment: @user3673985 did you check if there are other instances of val or similar keyword misuse. try cleaning the target and recompile from scratch. as shown in the example thats how we get "illegal start of simple pattern"

Comment: Tried those too but still issue persists :(